# How to :set spell in Vim only for emails?

Tags: email, vim, spell-checking, mutt

Google is not being very helpful here. I'd like to compose emails with `:set spell` on, but for all other files, `:set spell` should be off. I am using mutt, and Vim as the editor for composing emails.

In fact, I'm curious, how does Vim know that it's an email I'm composing? Is there a command-line parameter of the type of file being edited? How does mutt know what to pass in?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use an autocmd in your `~/.vimrc` that gets triggered by the detected file type:

```
autocmd FileType mail set spell
```

Comment: How does Vim know that it's an email I am composing?

Comment: Vim knows mutts naming scheme for temporary files. If a file fits that pattern, vim treats it as a mail. (For details look into your filetype.vim that is probably located somewhere in /usr/share/vim)

Comment: Exactly! I would prefer this method over the "set editor" line, since it allows you also to set the spelllang and other options, in a more readable manner...

Comment: Exactly, I use this setup to set things like textwidth, nonu, nocursor, etc.

Answer (score 8):

Try this in your .muttrc:

```
set editor = "/usr/bin/vim -c':set spell'"
```

You can find the correct path to vim with "which vim".

Comment: Perfect thanks.

It doesn't seem like mutt requires the full path to vim, which is great if I want to use the same muttrc file across platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be using a mutt configuration command? See the following links:

- Text Editing: http://mutt.blackfish.org.uk/editing/

Answer (score 0):

Add the following into your ~/.vimrc:

```
set spelllang=en_gb,fr
au BufRead,BufNewFile *mutt* set filetype=mail
autocmd FileType mail set spell
```

And it should work fine.  You can (should?) change the spelllang to reflect any languages that your routinely use.